# What does target mean in drag and drop of HTML elements

Tags: javascript, html

I was reading this w3 schools code on drag and drop and got a bit confusion.What does the "target" in the code mean(I hope it must be the dropable element).
 `ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);`//In this line it is mentioned that ev.target.id is the value of the dragable element...but here

ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data)); //the value of the dragable element(data) is appended to ev.target which must be the dropable element as per the syntax.Kindly explain me if i'm wrong.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<img id="drag1" src="img_logo.gif" draggable="true"
ondragstart="drag(event)" width="336" height="69">

</body>
</html>
```

Code explained:

Call preventDefault() to prevent the browser default handling of the data (default is open as link on drop)
Get the dragged data with the dataTransfer.getData() method. This method will return any data that was set to the same type in the setData() method
The dragged data is the id of the dragged element ("drag1")
Append the dragged element into the drop element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`target` refers to the element which triggered the event.

> A reference to the object that dispatched the event. It is different from event.currentTarget when the event handler is called during the bubbling or capturing phase of the event.

**HTML**

```
<div id="test">Click Me!</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var id = e.target.id;

    console.log(id);
    console.log(e.target);
});
```

**Output**

[image]

**JSFiddle**

Open the console and check the output,

[Live Example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb6zw817/1/)

**Reading Material**

[`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

Comment: So during drag the target will be drag1 and during drop the target will be div1 according to the W3 schools code..Is that rit?

Comment: @Nivetha precisely.